# Datastage 11.7 odbc connector error loading data into SQL Server

Tags: etl, datastage, mysql-odbc-connector

I am trying to Extract data from Snowflake,put it in a dataset and use that to Load the same table in SQL Server.

Extract part executed without any issues but when i am trying to load into SQl server i am getting this error. "Designed Schema field Name:A INT64 type was not found in external Schema". i could see both in Snowflake and SQL it has same datatypes and length.moreover the insert statement was something like this INSERT INTO A() VALUES() i.e empty.odbc connector is not assigning the values from the source dataset.

Error i found in IBM Documentation:
IIS-CONN-DAAPI-000064I External schema field, name: field name, type: field type was not found in the design schema